# use create_dendrogram with a phylogenetic tree

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, plotly, biopython, phylogeny

i'm pretty newbie with plotly and i have absolutly no idea how (and if it's possible) to change my code to use it with a phylogenetic tree.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

data = np.genfromtxt("AAI_matrix.csv",names=True,usecols=tuple(range(1,36)),dtype=float, delimiter="\t")
data_array = data.view((np.float, len(data.dtype.names)))
data_array = data_array.transpose()
labels = data.dtype.names

fig = ff.create_dendrogram(data_array, orientation='bottom', labels=labels)
```

this is my "main" code to create this plot

[image]

which is working so well! but i would like to create the same kind of plot but instead of having some dendogramm with clustering i would like to put my phylogenetic tree (in newick format) and reorder all the data according to this tree. is it possible? thanks for your help!

Comment: Ya, possible, If u provide some minimal data, I will help u